# Install ubuntu on a system which does not load

Tags: system-installation

I have a core i3, 8GB RAM, ASUS desktop computer which ran windows 10. When installing java updates, It crashed and does not load anymore. Now I decided to say goodbye to windows and install Ubuntu instead. I have so many data on my PC and I need them, so should I reinstall the windows 10 first, and then install Ubuntu? Can I just install Ubuntu without losing data?
I don't want dual boot and I'm new to Ubuntu :)

Comment: Impossible to answer w/o details "Can I just install Ubuntu without losing data? " can be yes or no depending on your systems layout. Mind though: having an NTFS partition w/o Windows is bad Also: going  into Ubuntu cold turkey is bad too. Windows aint Linux. Then again: why not make a backup of your personal files 1st? You can do that w/o having to log into your system from the live session prior to installing,

Comment: you mean Ubuntu let me see my personal files (and probably  back them up) before installing OS? That's great !

Comment: yes. the live session you use lets you explore linux to see if it all works prior to installing. so it also lets you mount your disks (incl, windows) so you can use an usb to write your files to it. Or set up internet access and connect to google drive or another online service

Comment: It's amazing! I would use the live session and backup my files then install Ubuntu.It sounds so much better than windows. Thank you